# N balls in a jar where the probability of the i_{th} ball being chosen is P_{i}. M students choosing one ball each with replacement. Probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, permutations, multinomial-distribution

So this question was given to my class by our CS Professor as a challenge. It goes as follows:

#### There is a jar which contains $N$ balls and there are $M$ students. The probability of the $i$<sub>th</sub> ball being chosen is $P_i$. Each student selects only one ball independently with replacement (the number of balls remain the same after choosing). Find the probability that atleast two students will select the same ball.

**My approach:**
First of all, if $N<M$, then the probability has to be $1$ because there are more students than balls.

Now, in the case when $N \geqslant M$:

Let's suppose the set of all probabilities of the balls is $P = \{P_1, P_2, P_3, \ldots , P_n\}$ and there are $M$ students to choose them. We'll calculate the Probability $P(E)$ which represents the probability of each student selecting a unique ball.

So, the final answer would be $1 - P(E)$. Now, let us consider $perm_i$ to be a subsequence of $P$ containing $M$ elements (unique choice of balls made by each student). And we calculate the possible ways to create all the $perm_i$ subsequences. The number of ways to do it is $^N\!C_M$. This way, we create an array named $perm$ which contains all $^N\!C_M$ number of $perm_i$.

Here we consider one subsequence, suppose $perm_1$ which contains $M$ elements. For the first ball, there may be $M$ students who choose it. Again, for the second ball, there are $M-1$ unique students left to choose it. As we go on, for the $M$<sub>th</sub> ball, only 1 unique student is left.

So, the probability for this permutation is: $(P_1 \times M) \times (P_2 \times (M - 1)) \times \cdots \times (P_M \times 1)$.

Or, simplified as : $P_1 \cdots P_M \times M!$. Again, we would have to do this $^NC_M$ number of times over the set $perm$ for every possible $perm_i$.

Thus,
$$
P(E) = \sum_{i=1}^{^N\!C_M} \prod perm_i M!
$$

Is this the correct way to do it, or am I wrong somewhere? Could this solution be simplified more?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Cactus

Comment: Your header says *without replacement* whereas the body says *with replacement*. Which is it ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.. It's 'with replacement' (no. of balls remain same after choosing)

Comment: Are you also saying that , probability of selection of  a ball may differ from ball to ball   ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes, and that's the main catch of the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, the main catch is that each ball has a possibly different probability of being chosen, but your answer is not correct.

*There is only one trial*, and the probability is to be assessed for that one trial.

With $N>M$,there will be $\binom{N}{M}$ *distinct*  combinations (no repeats) of $M$  elements, thus P(get a distinct combo) $=\frac{\binom{N}{M}}{N^M}$

Arranging the elements of the distinct combo obtained (say $j_{th}$ combo) in ascending order, the **combo's** probability is  $$P_j= P_{j_1}*P_{j_2}*...P_{j_M}$$
and since the elements can be assigned to people in $M!$ ways,

P(distinct elements drawn $\cap$ no assigned element common )$= M!P_j\frac{\binom{N}{M}}{N^M}$,

and finally, P(at least two people draw a common element $$= 1 - M!P_j\frac{\binom{N}{M}}{N^M}$$

---

### Added

If you say that the intention is repeated trials, (in which case we are actually computing *expected probability*, your answer is correct, I'd only change the terminology *perm_i* to *combo_i* as they are combinations. (Better still, make it $C_i$)

Also, I'd suggest that you put $1- P(E)$ at the end as the final answer

Comment: Alright, but one I thing which I couldn't understand is that why aren't you adding up the probabilities for each possible permutation of P. Why just choosing a selective set of Pj?

Comment: @true blue anil: That's a clever solution but why don't you have to multiply the denominator ( the $N^M$ term ) by each of its probabilities also ?

Comment: @PrabhatSharma: It is not a selective set. To draw distinct balls, we  need to draw just *any one* combo that doesn't have repeats, and we then consider the probabilities for *that* combo.

Comment: @markleeds: We first found out *fraction* of draws that won't have repeats, by $\dfrac{\binom{N}{M}}{N^M}$, numerator gives selections with distinct elements, denominator give all possible selections, then  we consider probabilities of only the combo that actually got selected from the numerator.

Comment: @PrabhatSharma: If *repeated* trials had been mentioned, we would have had to proceed differently.

Comment: @PrabhatSharma: See the *Added* part I have put for repeated trials

Comment: @true blue anil: thanks for your answer and your explanation makes sense. just one last question: Is $P_j$ the same for all $j$ so just some fixed constant. thanks.

Comment: @markleeds: No, that's what makes it complicated.

Comment: Right, but can you explain it with a more intuitive example as to why my answer fails in the case of no repeated trials.

Comment: Take a very small example, $4$ balls $A,B,C,D$ with respective probabilities $0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4$ of getting drawn, and two persons drawing it. So suppose persons $1,2,$ draw balls $A,B, Pr= 0.02$, but if they draw  balls $B,C, Pr=0.06$

Comment: @true blue anil: I'm sorry to be such a pest, but, if that's the case, ( $P_j$ is not a fixed constant ), are you saying that there is no closed form solution since one would not know $P_{j}$ beforehand. So the expression that you came up with cannot be computed since you don't know $j$ ?

Comment: @markleeds: For a single trial, I will not be able to know the probability beforehand. We can only know the *expected* probability if we are to throw *all* possible combinatons,